# Sed is not writing to file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cat

I wanna simply change the delimiter on my CSV.
The file comes from a outside server, so the delimiter is something like this: ^A.

```
name^Atype^Avalue^A
john^Ab^A500
mary^Ac^A400
jack^Ad^A200
```

I want to get this:

```
name,type,value
john,b,500
mary,c,400
jack,d,200
```

I need to change it to a comma(,) or a tab(,), but my sed command, despite correctly output, does not write the file.

```
cat -v CSVFILE | sed -i "s/\^A/,/g"
```

When i use the line above, it correctly outputs the file delimited by a comma instead of ^A, but it doesn't write to the file.

I also tried like this:

```
sed -i "s/\^A/,/g" CSVFILE
```

Does not work also...
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The first command could not work. You let sed operate on the piped data, there is no file that sed can see and rewrite inplace. Your second command instead seems ok. Is there an error message?

Comment: Please provide some examples lines from the file. Especially the `cat -v` does some transformation probably creating the `^A` that is not there in your second example.

Comment: on second command there is no error message. it simply does not edit the file, it remains the same.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which shell are you using? Try using single quotes around the regular expression?

Comment: I believe that the `^A` is not in the file. There is some nonprintable character, that cat -v displays as `^A`. So you could do: `cat -v CSVFILE | sed "s/\^A/,/g" > CSVFILE.rpl`` and then rename CSVFILE.rpl afterwards.

Comment: I believe your `^A` is the char with byte representation 1, use `sed -i 's/\x01/,/g" CSVFILE'

Comment: To insert ^A character in your pattern : Ctrl + V + A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ***Literal* `^A` (two characters, `^` and `A`) is how `cat -v` *visualizes* control character `0x1`** (ASCII code `1`, named `SOH` (start of heading)). `^A` is an example of [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) to *represent* unprintable ASCII characters:

  - `^A` stands for keyboard combination <kbd>Control-A</kbd>, which, when preceded by generic escape sequence <kbd>Control-V</kbd>, is how you can create the *actual* control character in your terminal; in other words,
    <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Control-A</kbd> will insert an actual `0x1` character.
  - Incidentally, the logic of caret notation (`^<letter>`) is: the letter corresponds to the ASCII value of the control character represented; e.g., `A` corresponds to `0x1`, and `D` corresponds to `0x4` (`^D`, `EOT`).
    To put it differently: you add `0x40` to the ASCII value of the control character to get the ASCII value of its letter representation in caret notation.
    `^@` to represent `NUL` (`0x0` characters) and `^?` to represent `DEL` (`0x7f`) are consistent with this notation, because `@` has ASCII value `0x40` (i.e., it comes just before `A` (`0x41`) in the ASCII table) and `0x40 + 0x7f` constrained to 7 bits (bit-ANDed with the max. ASCII value `0x7f`) yields `0x3f`, which is the ASCII value of `?`.
  - To **inspect a given file for the *ASCII values* of exotic control characters**, you can **pipe it to `od -c`**, which represents `0x1` as (octal) `001`.
- This implies that, **when passing the file to `sed` *directly*, you cannot use caret notation and must instead use the *actual control character*** in your `s` call.

  - Note that when you use <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Control-A</kbd> to create an *actual* `0x1` character, it will also *appear* in caret notation - as `^A` - but in that case it is just the *terminal*'s visualization of the true control character; while it may *look* like the two printable characters `^` and `A`, it is *not*. Purely visually you cannot tell the difference - which is why **using an escape sequence or ANSI C-quoted string to represent the control character is the better choice** - see below.
- Assuming your shell is `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`, the better alternative to using <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Control-A</kbd> is to **use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to generate the `0x1` character:  `$'\1'`**

  - However, as [Lars Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086774/lars-fischer) points out in a comment on the question, **GNU `sed` also recognizes escape sequence `\x01`** for `0x1`.

Thus, your command should be:

```
sed -i 's/\x01/,/g' CSVFILE    # \x01 only recognized by GNU sed
```

or, using an ANSI C-quoted string:

```
sed -i $'s/\1/,/g' CSVFILE
```

<sup>Note: While this form can *in principle* be used with **BSD/OSX `sed`**, the `-i` syntax is slightly different: you'd have to use `sed -i '' $'s/\1/,/g' CSVFILE`</sup>

---

The only reason to use `sed` for your task is to take advantage of in-place updating (`-i`); otherwise, `tr` is the better choice - see [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35661790/45375).

Comment: 'when passing the file to sed directly, you cannot use caret notation' : not exactly, it depends on the editor. In Vim the keyboard combination  CTRL-V CTRL-A  creates a single character (the actual Control character displayed `^A`) that is correctly matched by sed.

Comment: @Kenavoz: What you're describing is not caret notation per se, but the terminal's visualization of a control character that also happens to use caret notation; I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I'll remember that `\x01` and `$'\1'` are an alternative for better portability.

Answer (score 1):

If your `sed` supports the -i option, you could use it like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\^A/,/g" CSVFILE
```

(This assumes the delimiter in the source file consists of the two characters ^ and A; if ^A is supposed to refer to Control-A, then you will have to make adjustments accordingly, e.g. using `'s/\x01/,/g'`.)

Otherwise, assuming you want to keep a copy of the original file (e.g. in case the result is not what you expect -- see below), an incantation such as the following can be used:

```
mv CSVFILE CSVFILE.bak  &&  sed "s/\^A/,/g" CSVFILE.bak > CSVFILE
```

As pointed out elsewhere, if the source-file separator is Control-A, you could also use `tr '\001' ,` (or `tr '\001' '\t'` for a tab).

The caution is that the delimiter in the source file might well be used precisely because commas might appear in the "values" that the separator-character is separating.  If that is a possibility, then a different approach will be needed.  (See e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

Answer (score 1):

In case it's run under OS X :

- Add an extension to the `-i` to write in a new file :

  ```
  sed -i.bak "s/^A/,/g" CSVFILE
  ```
- Or to write in place :

  ```
  sed -i '' "s/^A/,/g" CSVFILE
  ```
- You can also output to file with a cat but without `-i` on your sed
  command :

  ```
  cat -v CSVFILE | sed "s/^A/,/g" > ouput
  ```

Make sure you write the ^A this way :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: While you are correct that `-i` _requires_ an option-argument on OSX, the question is tagged [tag:linux], and on Linux it is `-i ''` that won't work.

Comment: OS X is Unix-based, and it could be more relevant to choose a `linux` than a `mac os x` tag for this question. The reason why a simple `sed -i 's/\^A/,/g'` does not work was more seemingly that it was run on OS X. But i may be wrong...

Comment: If that it is your guess, I suggest stating that explicitly in your answer.
However, I think it's more likely that the tat is correct and that the problem stems from taking the `^A` visualization of control character `0x1` literally.

Comment: I updated my answer. But we're note sure `^A`was the problem ("it correctly outputs the file delimited by a comma instead of ^A").

Comment: Thanks for updating; re `^A`: that only worked because `cat -v` was applied to the file first.

Comment: So i guess it's a Mac OS X ;-)

Comment: No, it most likely _is_ Linux, and the problem was that the `sed -i` command also tried to replace _literal_ `^A`, even though the file was passed _directly_ to `sed` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the job `tr` was created to do:

```
tr '<control-A>' ',' < file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Replace `<control-A>` with a literal control-A obviously.

Comment: Nicely done; in Bash, Ksh, and Zsh you can use `$'\1'` to generate Control-A.

Comment: good to know, thanks. I'd typically do control-V control-a to get a literal one.

Comment: Come to think of it: `tr '\1' ','` should work as well.